# How to build a time series in R only with the maximum / minimum value up to tha date?

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to build a time series with only the maximum (or minimum) values up to that date.
For example, in column A we have the original values of the series and in column B the maximum values of the series up to that moment.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 9 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 7 | 9 |
| 9 | 9 |
| 11 | 11 |
| 12 | 12 |
| 12 | 12 |
| 13 | 13 |
| 15 | 15 |
| 16 | 16 |
| 15 | 16 |
| 16 | 16 |
| 18 | 18 |
| 21 | 21 |
| 23 | 23 |
| 21 | 23 |
| 20 | 23 |

Is there a way to operationalize this in R?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cummax/cummin`

```
df1$B <- cummax(df1$A)
df1$B 
#[1]  9  9  9  9 11 12 12 13 15 16 16 16 18 21 23 23 23
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(9L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 
16L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L
), class = "data.frame")
```